# Property 'data' is missing in type 'never[]' but required in type data product

Tags: typescript

Hi i am new in typescript please how can fix this error that says

> Property 'data' is missing in type 'never[]' but required in type '{ data: { products: []; }; }'.

here is by code:

```
let medias :[] = [];

let res :{
    data: {
        products: []
    },
} =[];

try {
    res = await axios.get('https://dummyjson.com/products?limit=10&skip=10');
    medias = res.data.products;
} catch (e) {
    medias = [];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least two problems:

1. You're having TypeScript infer the type of `res`, but using just `[]` as `products`. Since TypeScript doesn't know what the elemetns will be, it infers `never[]`. This issue applies both to `res`'s `products` and to `medias`.
2. You've said the type of `res` is an object with a `data` property, but then you're trying to initialize it with just `[]`.

Instead, use non-inferred types, and say expressly what type you expect in the array. You can also use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#handbook-content) type argument with `axios.get` (because it's a generic method) to say what you expect the `data` to be. For instance, **if** you're expecting an array of strings:

```
let medias: string[] = [];
//          ^^^^^^

try {
    const res = await axios.get<{ products: string[] }>(
    //                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        "https://dummyjson.com/products?limit=10&skip=10"
    );
    medias = res.data.products;
} catch (e) {
    // No need for `medias = []` here, you've already done it above
}
```

If you're expecting an array of something else, just use that instead of `string` above.